# Can I grow oyster mushrooms on shiitake-style blocks without bags?

Tags: fungus, mushrooms

can i do it or does it just not work that way

By shiitake-style I mean like this[image]

As opposed to the normal fruiting bag

[image]

If it is possible, do I have to use a different substrate so it would hold up?
Thank you.

Comment: "Shiitake-style block" there appears to be "log" - shiitake do well in logs *or* chips/sawdust. Oyster don't seem to be much for logs based on what methods are typically suggested, though I haven't looked for an alternate view as I don't think much of them for eating.

Comment: Do look up temperature and light requirements in addition to the obvious moisture one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you will have is huge losses of humidity resulting in the substrate drying out. If you are trying to avoid using plastic bags you could use buckets or containers instead.

Shiitakes require 85% humidity for pinning and fruit development, where as Oysters require 95% which is why plastic bags are unfortunately used because when they cut the bag mushrooms are provided with fresh air exchange + tons of humidity (between the plastic and the surface).

Comment: That makes sense. Shiitake mushroom blocks always look a little dry.

Answer (score 1):

So, I went and googled, and indeed "oyster mushroom log kits" are widely available, implying that using a log works fine with them as well.

Of course, the "log" process has differences from the "bag" process in handling and management, as you have an exposed log not a mostly-plastic-wrapped bag of sawdust. Moisture management is the big difference.

Some refer to log sections as "wood rounds" or "rounds"

Comment: Thank you. I think that while a log would work, doing sawdust blocks without a big might not, because Shiitake turn the bag brown after they colonize it and turn it into a hard block. Oyster might not do the same.